# C++ - Platform independent function for byte array to value and vice versa

Tags: c++, boost, casting, vector

I have these two functions in my project to convert a character array into a basic type (cast_chunk) and the other way around (uncast_type).

They are ugly and rely on underlying assumptions in the C++ compiler. Is there anything in std or boost that I can replace these with?

```
typedef uint8_t byte;
typedef std::vector<byte> data_chunk;

template<typename T>
T cast_chunk(data_chunk chunk, bool reverse=false)
{
    #ifdef BOOST_LITTLE_ENDIAN
        // do nothing
    #elif BOOST_BIG_ENDIAN
        reverse = !reverse;
    #else
        #error "Endian isn't defined!"
    #endif

    if (reverse)
        std::reverse(begin(chunk), end(chunk));

    T val = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(T) && i < chunk.size(); ++i)
        val += static_cast<T>(chunk[i]) << (i*8);
    return val;
}

template<typename T>
data_chunk uncast_type(T val, bool reverse=false)
{
    #ifdef BOOST_LITTLE_ENDIAN
        // do nothing
    #elif BOOST_BIG_ENDIAN
        reverse = !reverse;
    #else
        #error "Endian isn't defined!"
    #endif

    data_chunk chunk;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(T); ++i)
        chunk.push_back(reinterpret_cast<byte*>(&val)[i]);

    if (reverse)
        std::reverse(begin(chunk), end(chunk));
    return chunk;
}
```

Here's how they're normally used:

```
uint64_t val = 110;
data_chunk byte_array = uncast_type(val);
assert(val == cast_chunk<uint64_t>(byte_array);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The boost::endian library provides both [conversion functions](http://boost.cowic.de/rc/endian/doc/conversion.html) and [types with specified endianness](http://boost.cowic.de/rc/endian/doc/integers.html).

The four functions most like what you are doing are these:

```
template <class T> void native_to_big(T& x);
template <class T> void native_to_little(T& x);
template <class T> void big_to_native(T& x);
template <class T> void little_to_native(T& x);

template <class T> void native_to_big(T source, T& target);
template <class T> void native_to_little(T source, T& target);
template <class T> void big_to_native(T source, T& target);
template <class T> void little_to_native(T source, T& target);
```

Comment: Thanks, but how about converting between an integer and byte array though? Using reinterpret_cast to convert a uin64_t (as a uint8_t[8]) to an std::vector<uint8_t> doesn't feel like a good idea.

Comment: Also those functions and types do not exist in boost. I grepped the headers, and there's no boost/endian/ directory :( Otherwise they look super.

Comment: You may have a distribution of boost that's broken into pieces. You'll need to install the piece that contains [boost::endian](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/boost/detail/endian.hpp). And yes, I agree, using `reinterpret_cast` that way is not a good idea.